# put ArrayNode inside ObjectNode

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jackson, objectmapper

I would like to prepare an object as per below format. Array of objects inside an ObjectNode. I'm trying as per below.

{ [ {arrayNodeObject1}, {arrayNodeObject2}, {arrayNodeObject3} ] }

```
ArrayNode arrayNode = new ObjectMapper().createArrayNode();
arrayNode.add(arrayNodeObject1);
arrayNode.add(arrayNodeObject2);
arrayNode.add(arrayNodeObject3);
```

with the above code, I can able to get array of object as per below.

```
[{arrayNodeObject1}, {arrayNodeObject2}, {arrayNodeObject3}]
```

Now, I would like to put the above ArrayNode inside a ObjectNode. Please advise. Also, how can i read ArrayNode back from the ObjectNode.

If i can have a lable to the ArrayNode, it would be easy to get the arrayNode.

Answer (score 1):

This is how i did it using a stream:

```
ArrayNode arrayNode = mapper.createArrayNode();
arrayList.stream()
    .forEach(id -> arrayNode.add(id));
objectNode.set("Key", arrayNode);
```

Or for your example:

```
ArrayNode arrayNode = new ObjectMapper().createArrayNode();
arrayNode.add(arrayNodeObject1);
arrayNode.add(arrayNodeObject2);
arrayNode.add(arrayNodeObject3);
objectNode.set("Key", arrayNode);
```

To retrieve this you can use:

`objectNode.get("Key")`

**Note**

- `set()` has deprecated `put()` on `ObjectNode` to replace the use of put() where chaining with `this` is used. `set()` returns the node after adding/returning the property value

Answer (score 0):

I think maps are the way to go here if you want to have labels:

```
Map arrayNodeObjectMap = new HashMap<String, ArrayNode>();
arrayNodeMap.put("labelForArrayNodeObject1", arrayNodeObject1);
arrayNodeMap.put("labelForArrayNodeObject2", arrayNodeObject2);
arrayNodeMap.put("labelForArrayNodeObject3", arrayNodeObject3);
```